# Hibernate 4 - Calling DAO and Initializing sessionFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm in the middle of updating my old program to Spring 3.2 and Hibernate 4 and am running into a couple of difficulties with sessionFactory (I was using hibernateTemplate before).

1. I don't think the way I am accessing the DAO is the best way to do it, but I don't see how else to make it work.  If I do a simple creation of the DAO object (CSSDAO d = new CSSDAOImpl();), the sessionFactory is always null.  If I have it the way I do below, it works.  What is the proper way to call the DAO methods? (please ignore the MVC portion of the controller, I know that needs its own work)
2. I'm opening a new session in every method in the DAO.  I know this isn't correct, as I should be getting the current session.  But everytime I try to get the current session, it says one doesn't exist.  How does the session get "initialized" the first time?  I thought it would inject it based on the XML configuration, but that doesn't seem to be doing anything here.  Any thoughts?

**hibernate-cfg.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Steven\MyDB"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.form" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.form.StyleChooser</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="CSSDAO" class="dao.CSSDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**DAO:**

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import net.form.StyleChooser;

public class CSSDAOImpl implements CSSDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List selectAllCSS() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List l = session.createCriteria(StyleChooser.class).list();
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
        return l;
    }

    @Transactional
    public StyleChooser selectCSSById(Integer ID) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        StyleChooser sc = (StyleChooser) session.get(StyleChooser.class, ID);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();        
        return sc;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Integer insertCSS(StyleChooser insertCSS) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Integer id = (Integer) session.save(insertCSS);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
        return id;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteCSS(Integer CSSId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        StyleChooser sc = (StyleChooser) session.get(StyleChooser.class, CSSId);
        session.delete(sc);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateCSS(StyleChooser cssWithNewValues) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(cssWithNewValues);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();        
    }
}
```

Accessing DAO...

```
package net.controllers;

import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import net.form.StyleChooser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;
import dao.CSSDAOImpl;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/stylechoosertable.html")
public class IndexController extends MultiActionController {

    Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(
            "C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/Programming/workspace/CSSGeneratorHibernate4/WebContent/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
    CSSDAOImpl dao = (CSSDAOImpl) beanFactory.getBean("CSSDAO");

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showIndex(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        List<StyleChooser> styleChooser = dao.selectAllCSS();
        return new ModelAndView("stylechoosertable", "styleChooser", styleChooser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few observation:

1. In your retrieve methods, transaction shouldn't be used i.e. they should be non-transactional.
2. Add `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` in your configuration to recognize the transactional annotations.
3. If you use `@Transactional` annotation then don't need to use programmatic transactions. Add the propagation attribute in the `@Transactional` annotation as `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` and leave the transaction management to Hibernate.
4. For first time you need to open the session and if not closed you may use the same session next time. For getting the `session`,  better to use an utility method as below:

   ```
   private Session getSession(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    Session session = null;
    try{
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }catch(HibernateException hex){
        hex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(session == null && !session.isClosed()){
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
   }
   ```

**This way, you will get the session if available and open otherwise open a new session.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So I need to remove the transaction lines from the methods and leave the transactions to hibernate via Transactional annotation, correct?  Why do I have to open a new session?  I thought the config would create a sessionFactory and session via injection?  Is that not the case?  Lastly, how should the DAO be accessed exactly (question 1)

Comment: @user1795832: 1. Correct. Just ensure that config is correct and transactions are working as expected. 2. You are creating the session factory only. You need to get/create session using the session factory. 3. Refer https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects for DAO access pattern.

Comment: OK great, that works.  But I do get an exception every time getSession is called, so the current session from the sessionFactory never exists in any case.  Why is that?  Does the session get destroyed once it exits the transactional boundary?  Also, for the deleteCSS and updateCSS methods, I also have to call flush() for the queries to go through, but I don't have to for insertCSS.  Any ideas there?  PS sorry it keeps removing the @YOUR USER NAME when I put it in there for some reason, so not sure if you are notified or not.

Comment: @user1795832 I doubt that your been itself is getting recreated and hence not getting the old session. Try setting the `scope` of the of the `dao` bean. Regarding the `flush`, I don't think it is required, if  you are having your transactions working properly.

Comment: The updates and deletes don't take unless I flush.  I've read that the Transactional should take care of that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user1795832: try putting propagation as "REQUIRES_NEW"

Comment: I'm still finding my sessionFactory bean isn't being injected.  When I have code in the controller to get the bean (like in my code above), I can see upon startup:  INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file applicationContext.xml].  However when I do a regular create of the DAO (dao d = new dao()), it doesn't load the bean definitions upon startup from applicationContext.  Why would that be?  I would guess I need something in dispatcher-servlet or web xml's?  I know import doesn't work as it adds sessionFactory, CSSDAO beans into DefaultListableBeanFactory.